# Online form/survey creation service

Tags: web-apps, survey

Looking for a simple drag/drop interface to create an online questionnaire. Able to spend up to $200(USD) per month.

**Requirements**:

- Versioned. Or at least allow respondent can make changes to their previous answers
- File upload
- Authenticated Respondents (must create account, or be invited to
  respond i.e. private)
- Simple logic - show question if respondent gives selected answer
- Export data
- Branding - logo and colors

**Nice to Have**:

- Admin only view. Admin can make notes on responses that are not visible to respondent - It would be nice to have 2 views of the data, one public and the other admin only.
- Reports. Don't want the data to be cumulative - each respondent should have their own report.

So far I am checking out these services (in order of best match):

- http://www.wufoo.com/features/
- http://www.orbeon.com/
- Google Forms

None of them seem to meet all the requirements, so I am looking for recommendations here

Comment: So you are looking for a service (as web app), and not something for hosting it yourself?

Comment: That is correct we are looking at SaaS. At the time I posted this, I didn't realize orbeon wasn't a hosted solution (it was mentioned by a coworker)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Survey Monkey may be a good option for you. It does not hit all of your requirements, see below.  [Feature/Pricing Chart](https://www.surveymonkey.com/pricing/upgrade/details/)

- Versioned. Or at least allow respondent can make changes to their previous answers  
  **I don't know that it can do this once the survey has been submitted, most surveys are not accessible once they have been submitted by design.**
- File upload 
   **Does not specifically mention this, and I have not used the paid features to test this.**
- Authenticated Respondents (must create account, or be invited to respond i.e. private) 
   **Yes**
- Simple logic - show question if respondent gives selected answer 
   **Yes, more advanced logic available as well**
- Export data 
    **Yes**
- Branding - logo and colors
   **Yes**