# Embeddable tool to allow users to create their own forms (similar to google forms)

Tags: html, forms

I'm looking for some sort of tool that I can include within a webpage that would allow my users to create a form for information-collection purposes, and would allow the form to later be filled out by other users. It would be a similar tool to google docs. I am looking for something that is embeddable in HTML, ideally an iframe or javascript plugin.

Comment: Related: [Open source or freeware tools for surveys (like Google Forms) but which allow image upload capability?](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2911/185) / [Online form/survey creation service](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2505/185)

Comment: @Izzy The first of your linked ones looks pretty much like a duplicate, doesn't it?

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Close relative, yes. But OP here didn't explicitly request image upload capabilities (and thus either might not require or even might not wish to have that). Clarification from Gershom needed.

Comment: Hey all, thanks for the responses! LimeSurvey looks very close to what I want - but I've found a piece of software (http://dobtco.github.io/formbuilder/) that is more readily pluggable into a webpage. It doesn't support image uploads so it doesn't answer the duplicate question, but it is a superior answer to this question than LimeSurvey

Answer (score 2):

Here's the best thing I've found. It's very similar to what I had in mind.

http://dobtco.github.io/formbuilder/

[image: formbuilder screenshot]